# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSSetM...> was mutated while being enumerated.'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I don't understand problem, but I guess the problem in storyboard (In my constraints, because sometimes objects isn't where they must be).

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '***

```
Collection <__NSSetM: 0x7fae0b5e6900> was mutated while being enumerated.'
*** First throw call stack:

 - (
    0   CoreFoundation   __exceptionPreprocess + 165

    1   libobjc.A.dylib  objc_exception_throw + 45

    2   CoreFoundation __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 132

    3   Foundation  -[NSISEngine substituteOutAllOccurencesOfBodyVar:withExpression:] + 336

    4   Foundation -[NSISEngine pivotToMakeBodyVar:newHeadOfRowWithHead:andDropRow:] + 330

    5   Foundation   -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:] + 314

    6   Foundation  -[NSISEngine tryUsingArtificialVariableToAddConstraintWithMarker:rowBody:usingInfeasibilityHandlingBehavior:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 285

    7   Foundation  -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 691

    8   Foundation   -[NSLayoutConstraint _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:integralizationAdjustment:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 275

    9   Foundation   -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 220

    10  UIKit  -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 411

    11  UIKit -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraintWithoutUpdatingConstraintsArray:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 30

    12  UIKit [UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 243

    13  UIKit -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) addConstraints:]_block_invoke + 188

    14  Foundation [NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 155

    15  UIKit  [UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) addConstraints:] + 263

    16  UIKit-[UIView _setTraitStorageConstraints:] + 794
```

Comment: Are you using a foreach somewhere to iterate over a mutable array or dictionary or set or some kind of other collection? You might want to add an exception breakpoint in xcode and provide the code that causes the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem with auto layouts. You are using an Array or Dictionary or some NSSet object which is being **mutated** (values are being added to it) while being **enumerated** (values are being read form it).

This problem mainly arises when you populate something like an Array and then reload a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`

Comment: How are you so sure about this? Did you see the stacktrace? Cause it really suggests that autolayout is to blame...

Comment: Because I've come across this error myself. And have spent a fair amount of time before learning that the error is caused by repeatedly accessing an array while it is being populated. So I'm pretty sure about this. @luk2302 's comment points the same way

Comment: So, are you suggesting that system frameworks are immune to this kind of bugs? How do you explain the stacktrace?

Comment: No. The stacktrace gives you a hierarchy till the actual error. So it is safe to say that the deeper to go into the stacktrace, the farther you go away from the actual error. If you concentrate on the first 3 indexes of your stacktrace you will notice that iOS was trying to handle the enumeration before crashing.

Comment: Thank you, I solved my problem) The problem really was with reloading

Comment: Well, then "Give to Caesar what is Caesar’s" as they say! Kudos

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some other background thread and main thread call autolayout functions simultaneously. Check out other threads in the crash log.

Comment: How to fix this problem or how we can make atomic